# How does Word2Vec CBOW softmax work with multiple context words?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, word-embeddings, word2vec, softmax

I'm referring to following paper from Xin Rong - ["word2vec Parameter Learning Explained"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf), to be precise the equation (4):

$$
p(w_j|w_I) = \frac{\exp(\mathbf{v’}^{T}_{w_{j}}\mathbf{v}_{w_{I}})}{\sum_{j'=1}^{V}\exp(\mathbf{ v’}^{T}_{w_{j'}} \mathbf{ v}_{w_{I}})}
$$
Simply said, do I understand correctly that `wj` describes my target word and `wi` is the single context word?

Would the equation look different with multiple context words or does it remain the same because `wi` describes the average of all context words?

Edit: Added the equation in TeX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve correctly understood $w_j$ and $w_I$: they’re the target word and input word.

Section 1.2 goes into more detail about the CBOW case; I’m filling in the pieces that weren’t explicit.

The LHS of the equation would be different:
$$p(w_j \mid w_{I1}, \ldots, w_{IC})$$
to show that you’re conditioning on several input words.

The RHS is also different, because we no longer use $\mathbf{v}_{w_I}$ to represent the input. Instead, the numerator and denominator should both replace that term with $\bf h$ from equation (18):

$$\mathbf{h} = \frac{1}{C} \left(\mathbf{v}_{w_{I1}} + \mathbf{v}_{w_{I2}} + \ldots + \mathbf{v}_{w_{IC}} \right)^T$$

This term averages the representations of the $C$ input words.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm at a loss here. How would the final equation look like? Do I insert $h$ into $v_{w_{I}}$ of (4)?

Comment: Yep! The results of that derivation are equations 19–21 in the paper. Another way to get the expression you’re looking for is to negate, then exponentiate, equation 19.

Comment: I know that I've already accepted your answer but I have one follow up question regarding equation 19-21. Am I understanding it correctly that $w_{o}$ is my actual target word from the vocabulary $V$ and $j*$ is the corresponding index in the output layer. Thanks again for helping me to understand it in depth, you can't imagine how grateful I am.

Comment: Yup, that’s what both are! They’re defined on page 3.